# PSU has 2 PCI-e cables, and I don't know how to use their endings or if I need to use ONLY one cable

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, cable, pci-express

I've started to assemble my new PC and when I've finally attached my Gygabyte NVIDIA GPU (GTX 760), it needs some kind of PSU power, in the form of 6 + 8 holed socket.
So far so good.

My PSU (Cooler Master G650 M), provides 2 PCI-e cables, and EACH of these 2 cables, provide this ending: 6+2 and 8 (cable 1), 6+2 and 8 (cable 2)

Ok, my doubt is: Can I use the "6+2" and "8" endings OF THE SAME cable? (leaving a full PCI-e cable unattached) 
Or do I have to use the 6+2 from one of the cables and the 8 from the other, using thus both cables at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: What does the manual say? It's normal to use a single PCI-e power cable for a single device though, wouldn't make sense, to use 2 cables for a single device

Comment: Nothing in either direction, just a drawing.

Comment: You should be able to use the 6+2 in one card. The idea is those who have dual/SLI setups then two cards will require power.

Comment: I don't understand if that answers my accurate question... I have just one card, but 6 + 8 holes...

Comment: Both those PCIe cables eventually hit the same internal power rail inside the PSU.

Comment: Ok, I'll try using the 6 + 8 pins from the same cable then...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either way. The reason for the multiple connectors is to stay within the power limitations of the connectors.